# Heroku: asset pipeline error to display images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I can't solve the problem to display image in `assets/images in production(Heroku). An image is displayed in development but that would not work in production only.

ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "category-1.jpeg" is not present in the asset pipeline.)

```
      <%= link_to category do %>
        <div class="categoryItem">
          <div class="image">
            <%= image_tag "category-#{category.id}.jpeg" %>
          </div>
          <div class="name">
            <span><%= category.name %></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overcome this by updating `production.rb` in `config/environments/production.rb`. Just set

```
config.assets.compile = true
```